# how to revert to 5 check-ins before HEAD without creating a new branch?

Tags: git

*How do I revert to 5 check-ins before HEAD (513b9c8)?*

I mean revert in the sense of, not losing any of the commits up to now.  I just want my newest check-in to look identical to 513b9c8 and I want HEAD to point to this new check-in.  I don't want any new branches.

I tried `git checkout 513b9c8` previously, but ran into problems with detached HEAD, etc...

**NOTE**

jszakmeister's answer below works perfectly.  Just **make sure you are at the top of your working tree** when executing the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git checkout 513b9c8 -- .` at the top of your working tree.  If you're happy with the result, then commit it.

This form of `git checkout` treats turns the commit hash into a tree hash, and then applies it to your working tree without changing which branch you are on.